# Extract a desired character from an alphanumeric column using concise REGEX in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am going through a "clean-up" process of a character column that holds employee rankings that should have a single character: 0-5 or M or U but instead it has up to 3 characters that are either numeric, alpha or alphanumeric.

I spent the better part of two days researching online (Regex, Stack overflow and Oracle resources) and testing and trying various options and the below "RESULT" (refer to code) is what I came up with. It does the job but I can't help but think that there is **a more concise way of doing this**. For example, at one point I thought I was close to accomplishing the task with a single instance of REGEXP_SUBSTR which used "|" (refer to PREV_TRY in code below). But then I couldn't figure out how to take this result and extract from it the first character for cases [1-4]{1}[ABCUL]{1} or the last character for all other cases.

Here is a reproducible example along with the solution I have so far:

```
WITH T AS (
SELECT 'M' EX FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'U' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1A'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL --some two character values are [1-4]{1}[ABCUL]{1}
SELECT TO_CHAR(ROWNUM) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL  <= 7 UNION ALL
SELECT '0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '113' FROM DUAL UNION ALL--if its numeric it can be 0-999
SELECT '03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL--some two character values are 0[1-4]{1}
SELECT '99' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RG1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL--some three character values are RG[1-4]{1}
SELECT 'NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL--some values are 'NA' or 'N/A'
SELECT null FROM DUAL --there are null values
)
SELECT EX
,NVL(SUBSTR(
        NVL(
            SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(EX,'(^(0|RG)?[0-5MU]?$)'),-1,1)
            ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(EX,'^[1-4]{1}[ABCUL]{1}'))
    ,1,1),0) RESULT --what I came up with so far
 ,NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR(EX,'(^(0|RG)?[0-5MU]?$)|(^[1-4]{1}[ABCUL]{1})'),0) PREV_TRY
 FROM T
```

I summarize what I need to accomplish with these rules:

- if its a single character then return any character that matches
  [0-5MU].
- if its a single digit followed by a single alpha character then
  return the digit [1-4]{1}[ABCUL]{1}. E.g., '2A' returns '2'
- if its RG[1-4] then return the digit. E.g., 'RG3' returns '3'
- if its 0[1-4] then return the second digit. E.g., '03' returns '3'
- all else return 0

Comment: What if the input doesn't match any of those? For example, what if it is a two-letter string, no digits? Or are you saying that that's not possible in the data, the ONLY possible forms of the string are the ones you enumerated? Also, what if you have a single digit followed by a single letter, but the digit is not between 0 and 5? Not possible? Or "return 0 in all such cases"? For RG[1-4] - OK, but what if it's RG5? Still return 0, not 5?

Comment: In all other cases return 0. What I included in the reproducible example, including the comments, are all the possible values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
WITH T (ex)AS (
SELECT 'M' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'U' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1A'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL --some two character values are [1-4]{1}[ABCUL]{1}
SELECT TO_CHAR(ROWNUM) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL  <= 7 UNION ALL
SELECT '0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '113' FROM DUAL UNION ALL--if its numeric it can be 0-999
SELECT '03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL--some two character values are 0[1-4]{1}
SELECT '99' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RG1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL--some three character values are RG[1-4]{1}
SELECT 'NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL--some values are 'NA' or 'N/A'
SELECT null FROM DUAL --there are null values
)
SELECT ex,
       COALESCE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           ex,
           '^([0-5MU])$|^(\d)[A-Z]$|^(RG|0)([1-4])$|^.*$',
           '\1\2\4'
         ),
         '0'
       ) AS replacement
FROM   t
```

Which outputs:

> | EX | REPLACEMENT |
> | --- | --- |
> | M | M |
> | U | U |
> | 1A | 1 |
> | 1 | 1 |
> | 2 | 2 |
> | 3 | 3 |
> | 4 | 4 |
> | 5 | 5 |
> | 6 | 0 |
> | 7 | 0 |
> | 0 | 0 |
> | 113 | 0 |
> | 3 | 3 |
> | 99 | 0 |
> | RG1 | 1 |
> | NA | 0 |
> | *<null>* | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4a5b2644fe96a3834aa3fb80ef1dba74)*

Comment: that was beautifully concise and exactly what I was thinking. Thank you! This fills in the holes for me for things I was trying to understand about regex, specifically the REGEXP_REPLACE Oracle SQL function, such as the relationship between groupings and back references. I ended up taking your function and testing variations of it to further my understanding.  One thing, non-regex related, I couldn't figure out, was it just preference, on why you choose to wrap it in Coalesce instead of NVL?

Comment: @daniellopez46 They both do the same thing; however, `COALESCE` is part of the ISO/ANSI standard and is used on multiple (almost all) RDBMS whereas `NVL` is an Oracle function and is not portable. But if you aren't worried about any of that then use them interchangeably.